# State space representation involving derivatives of input

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory

We have the system $y''=-7y'-12y-u'-2u$

If we choose $x_1=y,x_2=y'$ we can write the system as

$x'=Ax + Bu \\ y= Cx$

Finding A is easy, but how do I find expressions for $B$ and $C$ when we have derivatives of the input in the expression?

Comment: If you want $x_1,x_2$ be variables, shouldn't it be $x_1'=x_2, x_2'=-7x_2-12x_1-u'-2u$?

Comment: Yes, so we've found A, but what's B in that case?

Comment: Is $u$ also a variable? If so, you might have to let $x_3=u'$.

Comment: $u$ is the input. I don't think that's supposed to be a state variable.

Comment: See here: http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Representations/SysRepTransformations/TF2SS.html#Example:_Differential_Equation_to_State_Space_%28harder%29_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set $x_1=y$, $x_2=y'+u$ then 
\begin{align}
x_1'&=y'=x_2-u
\\
x_2'&=y''+u'=−7y′−12y−2u\\&=-7(x_2-u)-12x_1-2u\\&=-12x_1-7x_2+5u
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think inputs belonged in the state variables but I guess that's a neat solution. What's C here, then?

Comment: Oh, now I get it. Thanks again

Comment: Suppose if the physical meaning of y = position and u = force. What is the physical meaning of x2? We know that the x1 will be position, what is the physical meaning of x2? velocity + force?

Comment: Without any sensible interpretation of the original equation, it does not make much sense to ascribe physical semantics to computational tricks. Nevertheless, it is more that `u'` is a force, so that `-u` is some kind of potential of the force field. But that all is not very Newtonian or Hamiltonian.

Answer (score 2):

"Suppose if the physical meaning of $y =$ position and $u =$ force. What is the physical meaning of $x_2$? We know that the $x_1$ will be position, what is the physical meaning of $x_2$? velocity + force? – Unknown123"

You can find a very neat approach here:

https://www.ram.ewi.utwente.nl/aigaion/attachments/single/597

From that it is self-evident that the physical dimension of $y'+u$ comes from the physical dimension of the coefficients of variables.

From the equation  $$y′′=−7y′−12y−u′−2u,$$ if $y$ is a length, then $-u'$ and $-2u$ are accelerations, supposed the derivative is with respect to time; in case $u$ is intended to be a force, the coefficient $-2$ should rearrange dimensionality, and its physical meaning is the inverse of a mass. The coefficient of $u'$ has the dimensions of time/mass.

Comment: The link you shared is broken

Comment: Give us new link, please

Comment: Why -2 changed the dimensionality?

Comment: Ah I get it now. Suppose we have y = position and u = force. After that, we decide that x1 = position, x2 = velocity, Thus `x1 (m) = y (m)` and `x2 (m/s) = 1*(m/s) * y'(m/s) + 1*(s/kg) * u (kgm/s^2)`.

Comment: We need to decide what dimensions our state variables are first. That's our absolute reference. The state variables are fundamental entities and the coefficients derive from them.