# State-space realization of transfer function — controllable canonical form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, control-theory, linear-control

> Given the following transfer function $$ G(s) = \frac{100(s-2)}{(s-3)(s+4)}$$
> find matrices $A, B, C, D$ that realize the system.

---

I know that:

[image]

should be the solution, but I am trying to derive it alone and I am stuck.

I started out by:

$$ G(s) = \frac{Y(s)}{X(s)} = \frac{100(s-2)}{(s-3)(s+4)} \Rightarrow y'' +1y' -12y = 100x' -200x $$

but I can't figure out how to proceed.

The solution is:

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 12 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \qquad B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \qquad C = \begin{bmatrix} 100 & -200 \end{bmatrix} $$

Thank you for any tips!

Comment: What happened to $D$?

Comment: This question has been answered multiple times. Check the previous questions.

Comment: Check this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4510366/532783

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I need help to convert this dynamic system in a space state model](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4509870/i-need-help-to-convert-this-dynamic-system-in-a-space-state-model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transfer functions do not describe the ratio of the output and the state, but the ratio of the output and the input of a given linear time invariant (LTI) system.

So you have
$$
G(s)=\frac{Y(s)}{U(s)}=\frac{100(s-2)}{(s-3)(s+4)}
$$
and so
$$
\begin{align}
Y(s)(s-3)(s+4)&=U(s)100(s-2)\\
Y(s)s^2+Y(s)s-12 Y(s)&=100 U(s)s-200 U(s)
\end{align}
$$
and so
$$
\ddot{y}+\dot{y}-12y=100\dot{u}-200u
$$
Now there are two issues: You have a second derivative and an input derivative which are both not present in the state space form
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}=Ax+Bu\\
y=Cx+Du
\end{align}
$$
First we solve the problem of the second derivative by introducing state variables:
$$
\begin{align}
z_1&=y\\
z_2&=\dot{y}
\end{align}
$$
So you get
$$
\dot{z}_1=z_2,\dot{z}_2+z_2-12z_1=100\dot{u}-200u
$$
Solving for the state derivatives:
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{z}_1&=z_2\\
\dot{z}_2&=12z_1-z_2+100\dot{u}-200u\\
y&=z_1
\end{align}
$$
Now you only need to get rid of the input derivative. This is a question that has been answered several times on this site, for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1228305/369884) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1935486/369884). You can do this by defining
$$
\begin{align}
x_1&=z_1+a_1u\\
x_2&=z_2+a_2u
\end{align}
$$
Now differentiate ...
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}_1&=\dot{z}_1+a_1\dot{u}\\
\dot{x}_2&=\dot{z}_2+a_2\dot{u}
\end{align}
$$
... insert $\dot{z}_1,\dot{z}_2$ ...
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}_1&=z_2+a_1\dot{u}\\
\dot{x}_2&=12z_1-z_2+100\dot{u}-200u+a_2\dot{u}\\
y&=z_1
\end{align}
$$
... and replace $z_1$ with $x_1-a_1u$ and $z_2$ with $x_2-a_2u$ to get
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}_1&=x_2-a_2u+a_1\dot{u}\\
\dot{x}_2&=12(x_1-a_1u)-x_2+a_2u+100\dot{u}-200u+a_2\dot{u}\\
y&=x_1-a_1u
\end{align}
$$
We can see that $a_1$ is not helpful so set it to zero. However $a_2$ can be used to eliminate the $\dot{u}$ term by setting it to $-100$. So we have $a_1=0,a_2=-100$ and so
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}_1&=x_2+100u\\
\dot{x}_2&=12x_1-x_2-300u\\
y&=x_1
\end{align}
$$
Or, using the matrix form $\dot{x}=Ax+Bu, y=Cx+Du$ with
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\12&-1
\end{pmatrix},B=\begin{pmatrix}100\\-300\end{pmatrix},C=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\end{pmatrix},D=0
$$
This is different to the stated solution only up to a similarity transformation $q=Tx$ with
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
q_1\\q_2
\end{pmatrix}=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{50}&\frac{1}{300}\\
\frac{1}{200}&\frac{1}{600}
\end{pmatrix}}_{T}\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\x_2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
because the transformation used earlier is not unique. Apply this you get $\dot{q}=\hat{A}q+\hat{B}u,y=\hat{C}q+\hat{D}u$ with
$$
\hat{A}=TAT^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
-1&12\\1&0
\end{pmatrix},\hat{B}=TB=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix},\hat{C}=CT^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}100&-200\end{pmatrix},\hat{D}=D=0,
$$
i.e. the solution stated in your question.

Comment: While this works, there is a much simpler method as described here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4510366/532783

Comment: @KBS I agree, personally I would also prefer your method, but maybe this approach makes it more clear why we need state variables and similarity transformations in the first place. So I would see this method more for educational purpose while your method is more suitable for the "daily usage". But its a matter of taste of course.

Comment: That's fair enough!